# display BadRequest() message instead of redirecting to a page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

so i have this code

```
if(login.Email == null || login.Password == null)
    {
     return BadRequest("Please fill in all required fields!");
    }
```

How do I display the badrequest message on the front-end  ?

I tried using this

`<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>`

but it still redirects me to another page

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [Required] annotations on the Email and Password properties in your model? If you use those annotations, jQuery will handle the front end validation for you and then when you make it to the server you can call if(ModelState.IsValid()){ do stuff } instead of manually validating everything. 
[Reference Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation)